# Pandas Two Columns With Text - Applying GroupBy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to obtain the "DESIRED OUTCOME" shown in my image below. I have a somewhat messy way to do it that i came up with but I was hoping there is a more efficient way this could be done using Pandas? Please advise and thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: Do not post data as images, as images cannot be copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is pretty standard, and so is its solution: group by the first column and join the data in the second column. Note that the function `join` is not called but passed to `apply` as a parameter.

```
df.groupby('Name')['Food'].apply(';'.join)
#Name
#Gary    Oranges;Pizza
#John            Tacos
#Matt    Chicken;Steak
```

Answer (score 2):

You can group by `Name` column then `aggregate` with `';'.join` function

```py
df.groupby('Name').agg({'Food': ';'.join})
```